# YCSB Mongodb _id

Tags: mongodb, ycsb

I use ycsb to test mongodb.
After I load 3000000 documents, then I try to run insert step, but I encounter the problem below:

```
Exception while trying bulk insert with 0 com.mongodb.MongoWriteException: insertDocument :: 
caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error 
index: ycsb.usertable.$_id_  dup key: { : "user451605437247003858" }
```

I find that when I execute load step, the _id of the each document is somehow like

```
"_id" : "user1136", 
"_id" : "user1130"
```

and so on. It is not what I meet commonly like

```
"_id" : ObjectId("55753c547e2596a4d07c2219"),
```

So the conflict when I try to insert a lot documents is easy to understand.

So what can I do to solve the conflict?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the key you used to see like below :

```
"_id" : ObjectId("55753c547e2596a4d07c2219")
```

is generated by python driver **pymongo**.

The mongo module in YCSB uses [java driver](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/). When you call insert, actually you are calling :

```
com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection<TDocument>.insertOne
```

Which will throw

```
com.mongodb.MongoWriteException: E11000 duplicate key error collection
```

when you insert the same key.

**I don't think you need to worry about the err** if you want to run benchmark. Anyway, if you don't want to see the error, change your workload, replace insert by update.